# Combine two borders become one and set each function to the hover li

Tags: html, css

I have two questions here:

First: I have four `<li>` with its display is inline block and floating to left. I want **EACH `<li>`** has the style of the red colored border bottom **on mouse hover**.

Second: I want to make the border bottom of the text is **overlapped** with the border bottom of its wrapper (in this case is the `<ul>` of the `<li>`.)

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

And

```
#menu {
  list-style:none;
}

#menu li {
  display:inline-block;
}

#menu:hover li {
display:inline-block;
border-bottom:solid 5px red;
}
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/962rqnro/)

In the fiddle, the border colored blue is seperated with the border colored red. I want them **to become one border**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your CSS to:

```
#menu li:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:solid 5px red;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```

Firstly you want to apply the `:hover` to the individual `li` being hovered, and not all `li` when the `ul is hovered, then you want to offset its bottom (achieved with a negative`margin-bottom`) by the width of the border applied.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/962rqnro/2/)

Comment: Yes thanks that works. But how to set the each function in css?

Comment: @AlKush - you cant, they are at odds with one another- you cannot color a specific part of a given border a different color to the rest- without applying a separate border on a separate element

Comment: Thanks anyway. I want to accept the answer now but it asks me to wait in 9 minutes. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with smooth transition

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/962rqnro/3/)

```
#menu li:hover {
   border-bottom:solid 5px red;
   margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```